# Can I inherit one interface into another in typescript? How can I access the property defined in the inherited interface?

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance

Two interface are there first one is `ICat` and second one is `IMammal`.
`IMammal` extends `ICat`. Will the `Cat` property in `IMammal` have the capability to access all the property of `ICat` interface?

```
export interface ICat {
    Cateye: string[];
    Color: string;
    Name: string;
}

export interface IMammal extends ICat {
    Description: string;
    HasImage: boolean;
    CatGroup: string[];
    **Cat: ICat[]**;
}
```

Basically, how can I achieve multiple interface inheritances in Typescript?

Comment: I think you have gotten the inheritance backwards. A cat is always a mammal, but a mammal is not always a cat.

Answer (score 95):

I think maybe `ICat` should extend `IMammal` because Cat is a `Mammal`, and a `Mammal` do not need any references to `ICat`, think if you want to add `IDog` one day:

```
export interface IMammal {
    Description: string;
    HasImage: boolean;   
}

export interface ICat extends IMammal {
    Cateye: string[];
    CatGroup: string[];
    Color: string;    
    Name: string;
}

class Cat implements ICat {
    Cateye: string[];
    Color: string;    
    Name: string;
    Description: string;
    HasImage: boolean;   
    CatGroup: string[];
 }

const pusur:ICat = new Cat();
pusur.Name = "Pusur";
pusur.Description = "Likes lasagna";
pusur.CatGroup = ["Cartoon cat"];
```

Answer (score 7):

You use `implements` for interfaces, use `extends` for class inheritance. `implements` allows you to pass a list of interfaces which are implemented by the class.

Note that quite often it won't matter, as a class that implements all of the properties and methods of an interface is automatically compatible with the interface whether or not it explicitly `implements` the interface, but listing the interfaces explicitly at least means the compiler will tell you if you failed to implement them correctly.

```
interface A {
    a: string;
}

interface B {
    b: string;
}

class Foo implements A,B {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

function foo(b: B) {}
function bar(a: A) {}

const f = new Foo();
foo(f);
bar(f);
```